# zone.js:232 Error: Error: Unexpected value 'UserlistService' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: typescript, service, angular2-services

HiEveryone I am new to Angular 2 + typescript. I am creating small application where I am calling service and trying to fetch the  data, but I am getting following error. Can  anyone help please ?

This is my userschema.ts file.

```
export interface Userschema {
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
}
```

This is my Userservice.service.ts file.

```
import {Userschema} from "./userschema";

export class UserlistService {
    getAll() : Userschema[] {
        return [
            {fname: 'abc', lname: 'test'},
            {fname: 'xyz', lname: 'okl'},
            {fname: 'tuy', lname: 'los'},
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my userlist.component.ts file.

```
import {Component, style} from "@angular/core";
import {OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Userschema} from "../services/userschema";
import {UserlistService} from "../services/userService.service";
@Component({
   selector: "userlist",
   template:`
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let user of users">
                    {{user.fname}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        `
})
export class UserlistComponent {
   users: Userschema[] = [];

   constructor(private _userlistservice : UserlistService) {}
   ngOnInit(){
     this.users = this._userlistservice.getAll();
  }
}
```

Also This is my app.module.ts file.

```
import {HeaderComponent} from "./header-comp/header.component";
import {NetworthvalComponent} from "./networthval-comp/networthval.component";
import {SummaryTable} from "./summary-comp/summary.component";
import {StockPanel} from "./stockpanel-comp/stockpanel.component";
import {UserlistComponent} from "./userlist-comp/userlist.component";
/* Below tasks are default tasks. */
import {routing, appRoutingProviders} from './app.routing';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
       HttpModule,
       BrowserModule,
       FormsModule,
       routing
   ],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NetworthvalComponent,
    SummaryTable,
    StockPanel,
    UserlistComponent,
    /* Below task are default task.*/
],
providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And I am getting this error. Can anyone please tell me where I am missing what ? Sorry if I missed anything over here actually I am new to ANgular2 + Typescript so.

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us the code causing that error? It complains about the UserlistService being declared in AppModule, but it's not.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Yes it is same code. No difference.